# response written to page only on second request

Tags: node.js, httpmodule

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = process.argv[2];
var str="";
function onRequest(request, response) {
    str += "";
    console.log("Request received" + path);
    fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
        str += items;
    });
    response.writeHead(200, {"Context-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write(new Buffer(str).toString());
    response.end();
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
```

The above snippet creates a http server which gets a directory path from the user as argument. Make a http request to get the list of files available in the directory and send them back as a response.

The response is written to the page only on the second request. The page is shown empty on the first request.

Could anyone help. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is non blocking, so

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Context-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write(new Buffer(str).toString());
response.end();
```

will be executed before

```
str += items;
```

With

```
fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
    // Handle error
    str += items;
    response.writeHead(200, {"Context-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write(new Buffer(str).toString());
    response.end();
});
```

it will send the response after `readdir`.

And in Javascript the program will not be started for every new Request (like in PHP). So your global variable will be shared between all requests. If you don't want that put the `var str="";` in `onRequest`.

If you have multiple routes you also want to look into something like [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express), because the `http` module doesn't include routing.

Comment: stdin is a bit more complicated, because you don't know if all of stdin in read. Take a look at https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/5065599 or at a module like https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-stdin

Comment: process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
        path = process.stdin.read();
        console.log(path);
    });   unable to read using stdin

Comment: how did you start it. This snippet works with `echo abc | node script`

Comment: var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path;
process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
 path = process.stdin.read();
 console.log(path);
});
function onRequest(request, response) {
 console.log("Request received" + path);
 fs.readdir(path, function(err, items) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Context-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write(JSON.stringify(items));
  response.end();
 });
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
Here stdin isn't working

Comment: how do you input something in stdin?

Comment: Yea.. the input can be given but the response in the localhost isn't received. Throws error as "First argument must be string or buffer"

Comment: Because path is `null`. You need to check if it is null before like in all the examples